# UIButton under UIScrollView not responding to touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, constraints

I am facing a very strange problem. Trying to implement constraints to my view controller makes my button inactive.
My view hierarchy is

- UIVIew
- UISCrollView
- UIView
- UIView
- UIButton

There are many other views but just for simplicity. One thing is that there is an UIImageView object, which I am stretching to the view according to size but not objects are overlapping or similar, but might be related. 
Basically all the constraints are in storyboard. Only for the image view I am using manual setting.

```
self.imageViewHeight.constant=imgHeight;
```

when I disable auto layout the button works just fine.

EDIT: Latest observation :Just found out that simulator iPhone 6+ works fine with the constraints. The same is happening with a similar view, which is smaller so all iPhone works just 4S.
So it is definitely issue related to screen size and manipulating with constraints.
Looks like all objects that are bellow screen view itself after creation, so you have to scroll it to see them are inactive.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample project which demonstrates your issue?

Comment: The code works fine, the issue is related to storyboard and constraints when implemented.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm asking for a sample project. Since it's difficult figure autolayout issues without knowing all the constraints.

Comment: @Tobias thanx for trying to help me but unfortunately I cannot send it as a part since it's bit complex, and whole thing is for a customer which is not gonna be happy to share his project.

Comment: Hopefully someone else has run into a very similar problem and knows what to do. good luck.

Comment: One thing that's really helpful in debugging is setting all the views background colors to a different color, so you can see if anything is blocking your button.

Comment: Instead of setting all the view background colors just run in the simulator and select Color Blended Layers from the debug menu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to increase the frame Width or Height (whatever you need) of container view. The contentSize of scrollView only affects how it will scroll, which is irrelevant here.

If the button is outside the container view, it will still show up. However, it can't respond to any touch event.

**HERE WHAT WE NEED TO DO FOR TOUCH RESPONSE**

All you need to do is set bunch of constraints for CONTAINER VIEW of scrollview. Start from adding leading, trailing, bottom, top, width equal and height equal. Now in my case, I need fixed contentSize of Scrollview, so i change priority of equal width constraints to 750. For dynamic contentSize, you need to set priority programmatically.

[image]

Comment below if you have any query..

Thanks